# What causes "Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details." error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Nowadays I am seeing this error while `flutter run` or `flutter build` commands. Anyone knows what causes it? Is it something serious?

```
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-4.2.0+hotfix.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\share-0.6.3+6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\share\SharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-0.10.8+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\videoplayer\VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: the pacackage the you are using, its overriding a method which is marked as deprecated, this is what is causing that warning

Comment: is there a something that I "SHOULD" do, or is it just a notification that I just need to be aware of ?

Comment: just be awar of

Comment: is there a fix for that ? I updated the plugin causing that in my case google_maps_flutter-1.2,,, but I couldn't find a way to fix it yet

Comment: It is not on your side to do something, it is the maintainer of the plugin who should take action about deprecated APIs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the pacackage the you are using, its overriding a method which is marked as deprecated, this is what is causing that warning, its not something scary, but you should be aware of